# Python script to convert CAD DWG to shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, dwg

I'm trying to write a python script which will convert a CAD .dwg file to a shapefile (or GeoJSON - whichever is more viable)

I don't want to have to use `pyautocad` as that requires AutoCAD to be installed on the computer. I was hoping to use the likes of GeoPandas or shapely etc.

I've tried the below script as an initial take

```
import fiona
import geopandas as gpd

def convert_dwg_to_shapefile(dwg_file, shapefile):
    # Read the DWG file
    dwg = fiona.open(dwg_file, driver='DWG')

    # Retrieve the metadata and schema from the DWG file
    meta = dwg.meta
    schema = dwg.schema

    # Create the Shapefile
    with fiona.open(shapefile, 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema, crs=meta['crs']) as output:
        # Iterate over each feature in the DWG file and write it to the Shapefile
        for feature in dwg:
            output.write(feature)

    # Close the DWG file
    dwg.close()

# Specify the input DWG file and output Shapefile
input_dwg = 'input.dwg'
output_shapefile = 'output.shp'

# Convert the DWG file to Shapefile
convert_dwg_to_shapefile(input_dwg, output_shapefile)
```

but I'm getting the error `fiona.errors.DriverError: 'C....dwg' not recognized as a supported file format.` (I've removed the file path)

Are there any libraries like the above which can read a DWG? (free and without the need to install AutoCAD)

Comment: To convert CAD DWG (Drawing) files to Shapefiles in Python, you can use the Fiona library for reading and writing vector data, and OGR (part of the GDAL library) to handle the DWG files.

Comment: GDAL needs to be built with the with the Open Design Alliance Teigha library https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/oda.html to be able to read DWG.

Comment: @nmtoken ODA doesn't seem to be free though